# Ajax-driven complex layout RIAs and mvc frameworks

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, ria

I need to combine

- a ajax-driven RIA frontend, using for example JQuery layout plugin (http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html) or ExtJs (http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout/complex.html), with...
- a php mvc backend, using for example Zend MVC, CodeIgniter or Kohana

Where can I find info on how to set up the application structure/logic? What to put on the client/javascript side, and what on the server side? Maybe the traditional mvc framework paradigm with templates/views isn't the right thing here?

Links to examples, tutorials, blogs are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

quick response -- MVC can work great for ajax/RIA apps.  Just remember that a "view" doesn't necessarily mean displaying something to the user or rendering in the browser.  The view is the output of the program.  In this case, your view would likely be JSON data that is received and interpreted by jQuery.

hope that helps!
--Mark

Comment: Thank you, Mark! Maybe the creation/functional "flow" of a ajax-driven RIA could be described like this: 1) The client application (with its js libraries and structure) is served from the backend, in some kind of main template/view. 2) The application logic and presentation is handled by client-side javascript. 3) The backend responds to application requests as a data/resource server, mainly using json/xml. In other words - the mvc backend functions on two main "domains" - delivering/instatiating the client application, and responding to client data requests... Is this a correct description?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it.  There's not a lot of magic going on, just understanding "who" is requesting the information from the app.  Is it the browser for display to the user? Or is it the jQuery method that's looking for JSON or even raw HTML to plug back in to the DOM.

--M

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on incorporating [Backbone JS](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) (javascript mvc framework) with [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/). My understanding is that the ajax-driven front-end would "talk" with a Yii controller. The Yii Controller would serve as a RESTfull API, handling all interactions with the server-side database, and returning just the information that the client-side needs for its views (eg. as a json-encoded array).

Having said that, I am still figuring out how well this is going to work for complex web applications. I found a helpful [tutorial on integrating Yii and Backbone JS](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/) in this fashion.

I'm interested to hear how this works for you.